# URL encoding for spaces

Tags: php, url, encode

Is it possible to encode space to a '-' in the URL.

http://www.brandedproducts.com.au/Cotton%20Conference%20Bag%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20-34-1-0-0-IPPP1070

Kindly assist me.

[edit: fixed confusing 'a-']

Comment: Why would you want to use `a-` to encode a space? Did you mean `-` ?

Comment: You mean replace `%20` by `a-`?

Comment: Does that URL come from a variable that you are then using to redirect the user? if that is the case then you can manipulate the string by replacing certain part with the desired parts.

Comment: Hi konsolenfreddy.. Oops sorry.. Wanna replace it with '-'

Comment: Why are there so many whitespaces (looks weird)? And how do you think would you distinguish between `-` as whitespace and `-` as dash?

Answer (score 4):

```
str_replace('%20', '-', 'your url here');
```

Now I'm confused with the question, lol.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a rewrite rule to translate dashes into spaces, so when the request comes in it is properly handled.  The problem will be making the links correct when they are rendered.  You'll have to manually replace spaces with dashes before you do any sort of URLEncode.